# Get data between two second period and comma

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an AWS server name and I am trying to just get the domain name.
Here is an example of the server name:

```
SERVER1.SERVER2.US-WEST-5.RDS.AMAZONAWS.COM,59642
```

I just want to return:

```
US-WEST-5.RDS.AMAZONAWS.COM
```

I have tried using something similar to [this:](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/extracting-a-string-from-between-two-delimiting-characters)

But that is only for semi-colons. I know it is nested substrings and charindexes,

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using [SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
.

Returns part of a character, binary, text, or image expression in SQL Server.

Syntax

```
SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
```

Here is the implementation.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('SERVER1.SERVER2.US-WEST-5.RDS.AMAZONAWS.COM,59642', 
    1, CHARINDEX(',', 'SERVER1.SERVER2.US-WEST-5.RDS.AMAZONAWS.COM,59642') - 1) 
    AS FirstPart
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ceeb7835e38d776bbe27ad7606537486) demo.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option.  Perhaps a little overkill, but it demonstrates how you can parse a delimited string into columns.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'SERVER1.SERVER2.US-WEST-5.RDS.AMAZONAWS.COM,59642')
,(2,'SERVER1.SERVER2.US-WEST-6.RDS.AMAZONAWS.COM')       -- note no trailing ,
,(2,'SERVER1.SERVER2.US-WEST-6.RDS.DEV.AMAZONAWS.COM')   -- note extra DEV ,

Select A.ID
      ,NewStr = concat(pos3,'.'+pos4,'.'+pos5,'.'+pos6,'.'+pos7,'.'+pos8,'.'+pos9)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( left(SomeCol,charindex(',',SomeCol+',')-1 ))) B(CleanString)   -- Removes Trailing ,####
 Cross Apply (                                                                         -- Parses CleanString on .
                Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')                       -- Can be removed
                      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')                       -- Can be removed
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace(CleanString,'.','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) as A(xDim)
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  NewStr
1   US-WEST-5.RDS.AMAZONAWS.COM
2   US-WEST-6.RDS.AMAZONAWS.COM
2   US-WEST-6.RDS.DEV.AMAZONAWS.COM
```